# c# how to store values from a file in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to store values in an array from reading from a file.  I have the reading from a file part but I can't get it to store in an array because it gives me an error "Value cannot be null" because after the loop the value of my variable becomes null and the array cannot be null.  Here's what I have.  And I realize that the for loop probably isn't in the correct spot so any help with where to put it would be great.

```
    Program p = new Program();

        int MAX = 50;

        int[] grades = new int[MAX];

        string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";

        string path = environment + "grades.txt";

    StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path);

        string input;

        int count = 0;

        do
        {
            input = myFile.ReadLine();
            if (input != null)
            {
                WriteLine(input);
                count++;
            }
        } while (input != null);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            grades[i] = int.Parse(input);
        }
```

Comment: what is 'grades'

Comment: grades is the array in which I'm storing the values from a grades.txt file

Comment: You start the for loop just after exiting from the while loop. And the condition to exit from the while loop is true when input is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start the for loop just after exiting from the while loop. And the condition to exit from the while loop is true when input is null. Of course this is not well accepted by Int.Parse.
Instead you can use a single loop, taking in consideration that you don't want to loop more than 50 times otherwise you exceed the array dimensions

```
int count = 0;
while((input = myFile.ReadLine()) != null && count < 50)
{
    WriteLine(input);
    grades[count] = int.Parse(input);
    count++;
}
```

However you can have a more flexible way to handle your input if you use a `List<int>` instead of an array of integers. In this way you don't have to check for the number of lines present in your file

```
List<int> grades = new List<int>();
while((input = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    grades.Add(int.Parse(input));
```

Comment: thanks i appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

if we want to get really condensed

```
var grades = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(l=>Int.Parse(l)).ToArray();
```

Comment: `...Select(Int.Parse)` is 6 characters shorter plus `...ReadLines(...)` saves another 3.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov :-). I always forget that if the lambda is a simple function call i dont have to specify the args to it

Answer (score 0):

```
Program p = new Program();
int MAX = 50;
int[] grades = new int[MAX];
string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";
string path = environment + "grades.txt";
using (StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string input;
    int count = 0;
    while((!myFile.EndOfStream) && (count < MAX))
    {
        input = myFile.ReadLine();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            WriteLine(input);
            grades[count] = int.Parse(input);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

You should definitely use the "using" pattern around your stream object. Got rid of the for-loop for you while maintaining mostly your code and style.  Your issue was that you weren't using the input value before moving on to the next line.  You only ever had the last value in your original code.

Comment: IMHO - waaaay too complicated, Steve's solution is much easier to grok

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the `Path.Combine()` to help you in concatenating paths.

```
    string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    String fullPath = Path.Combine(environment, "grades.txt");

    int[] grades = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath).Select(p => int.Parse(p)).ToArray<int>();
    Console.WriteLine(grades);
```

[image]

Refer to https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readalllines on how to use `File.ReadAllLines()` its very handy.

I'm using LINQ here, which sometimes simplifies things. Even though it looks a bit intimidating now. We read all lines, the result of that is then parsed by selecting each one and converting it to an integer then outputting an array of integers and saving that to `grades`.